# Export Symbols of Static Library When Used for iOS App Creation

Tags: ios, static-libraries, debug-symbols

Some code packed up in a static library by me (using `libtool`) should be used in another project to build an iOS application. To make crash analysation possible, the .dSYM of the app should also contain the symbols of my static library. I assume I have to somehow either include the symbols in the library proberly or have to pass some symbols file to the build step that creates the .dSYM.

Is this possible? I am a bit overwhelmed by all the steps involved in the process of creating the .dSYM. If someone has some link with good information about this, I would appreciate that.

Also, how can I quickly determine all the symbols in the .dSYM?

Answer (score 5):

For static libraries to contain the required symbols, so they will be part of the apps dSYM when linking the static library to the app, you need to make sure the static library has the following build settings:

- Strip Debug Symbols During Copy: No
- Strip Style: Debugging Symbols
- Strip Linked Product: No

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the settings, but my crash report still does not symbolicate "fully": I do get the name of the function in the log but nothing else, i.e no line number - is this actually all I will ever get?

Comment: This worked for me, though the settings were applied to the target that creates the static library (not the app binary); it sounds like you are creating your static library outside of Xcode and so will need to adjust your settings there.